# Could not locate file config.xml at null: no protocol: config.xml - how to set path of config.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

So I'm working on a basic webapp that uses HTML, CSS, and AngularJS, and I've started to add functionality with Spring. As I added a few JARs, I started getting the error 
`DEBUG DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file config.xml at null: no protocol: config.xml`
It seems that it can't find my config.xml document which is currently at `src/main/resources`, but I've tried other addresses. Where can I set the path where I have the file instead of having it be `null`?

Comment: Without seeing your actual error log output, it is hard to say. Be wary that some message might be displayed right before an internal library handles the exception and tries an alternate location. In other words, that log line might not actually be the [final] cause of your program's failure.

Answer (score -1):

The resource loading can be tricky  in Java , the below class will load resources for you in desktop, web, within classpath , or current working directory:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JKResourceLoader {

    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resourceName) {
        URL url = getResourceUrl(resourceName);
        if (url != null) {
            try {
                return url.openStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public URL getResourceUrl(String fileName) {
        if (fileName == null) {
            return null;
        }
        URL resource = getClass().getResource(fileName);
        if (resource == null) {
            resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
            if (resource == null) {
                resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName);
                if (resource == null) {
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        try {
                            resource = file.toURI().toURL();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Also, you can use my [jk-util](https://github.com/kiswanij/jk-util) project by including maven dependency as follows :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jalalkiswani</groupId>
    <artifactId>jk-util</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

and just call the below code :

```
InputStream in = JKResourceLoaderFactory.getResourceLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.xml");
```